# 16 byte unsigned char array as a number?

Tags: c, arrays, encryption, casting, type-conversion

I am doing some cryptography with 128bit keys which necessitates using 16byte data chunks which I am storing as 16 byte unsigned char arrays.

```
unsigned char nonce_counter[16] = "xCv6Jk0neeV5GoSZ";
```

I frequently need to treat the value as a number to do some math, but I can't seem to find a safe way to type-cast the value.

*How can I cast a 16byte value to a numerical data type?*

Specifically, I need to use bitwise XOR **A^B** and increment **A++**.

I know I could do the obvious and use a for loop and deal with each element of the array independently, but I am concerned about the efficiency lost in doing so.

My system does not support `__uint128_t`.

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question?

Comment: @JacobG. I accidentally submitted before I intended to and started editing as soon as I did so, but thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: It's possible if you have a compatible int128_t and the order of the bytes in the array actually matches the endianess of your system architecture.  Otherwise, you may find it is just as fast to iterate over the bytes or possibly two or four bytes at a time, depending on endianess.

Comment: assuming you had a 16 byte int value you actually could, but you would run into endianness issues...

Comment: Is your application sensitive to that level of efficiency? How often are you performing that kind of processing on that kind of number?

Comment: @lurker I'm writing this for a network chip and this will be run on all data sent and received two times, once for authentication and once for encryption/decryption. So yes this will be run a fair bit depending on how much data is sent/received.

Comment: Does that string represent a base 64 number or is really an array of bits that happen to have those ASCII values?

Comment: Can we assume network byte order on the array/number?

Comment: Do you have any 128 bit integer support?

Comment: Do you have inttypes.h ?

Comment: @jwdonahue Its just a block of data I'm doing encryption on it so the data is free of context but for practical purposes, the data is just a large array of bits. And sadly __uint128_t  is not supported.

Comment: @lancegerday, Not all systems have __uint128_t, but they might have 128 bit integers of some kind.  What about inttypes.h?  Have you got one of those? Also, how wide are your native integers?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I cast a 16byte value to a numerical data type?
>   My system does not support __uint128_t.

If the compiler does not support 128 bit type, then there is no numerical data type solution.

---

A useful alternative is a `union`.

Avoid casting an character array pointer to a pointer of wider integers.  It can cause alignment errors (bus fault).

It is more clear to use `uint8_t` rather than `unsigned char` for this type of application.

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef union {
  uint8_t u8[16];
  uint64_t u64[2];
} my_uint128;
```

Code like the below will need to address endian concerns.

```
void foo() {
  my_uint128 nonce_counter = { .u8 =  "xCv6Jk0neeV5GoSZ"};
  btoh_128(&nonce_counter); // this would be a no-op on a BE machine
  ...
```

`^` is endian safe.

```
inline my_uint128 xor_128(my_uint128 a, my_uint128 b) {
  return (my_uint128) { .u64[0] = a.u64[0] ^ b.u64[0], .u64[1] = a.u64[1] ^ b.u64[1]};
}
```

Increment takes a little more work.  `LSB_128` defined as 0 or 1 depending on endian.

```
inline my_uint128 inc_128(my_uint128 a) {
  if (++a.u64[LS_128] == 0) { 
    ++a.u64[MS_128]
  }
  return a;
}
```

---

> I am concerned about the efficiency lost in doing so.

Try the above and verify efficiency lost before abandoning this approach.  Give your compiler a chance to optimize.

---

An alternative to `uint64_t u64[2];` and `LS_128` would be `struct { uint64_t ms,ls; };` with `ls, ms` ordered per the platform's endian.

---

One advantage to this approach is that the `union` could include a `uint128_t` member, if and when supported.  Then various routines could  use  direct 128-bit math without changing the calling code.

Comment: We don't even know if the OP has 64 bit integers available.

Comment: @jwdonahue re: [if the OP has 64 bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875399/16-byte-unsigned-char-array-as-a-number/48876016?noredirect=1#comment84756268_48876016)  True, yet all compliant C compilers since C99 have `unsigned long long` which is at least 64-bits.  So not too much of an assumption.

Comment: Actually, for embedded systems, that can be a really huge leap. The OP mentioned somewhere about running the code on networking chip.

Comment: @jwdonahue The embedded work I do supports 64-bit types, even with a 16-bit processor and modest compiler.  So OP, (lancegerday) what compiler are you using?

Comment: Yup, that's why I asked them what capabilities they have.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using gcc you can use `__uint128_t` pointer and modify the array trough it:

```
unsigned char nonce_counter[16] = "xCv6Jk0neeV5GoSZ";
__uint128_t* A = (__uint128_t*)nonce_counter;

*A += 1;
*A ^= *B;
```

Comment: See my comment on endianess.  It's not just about compiler support for 128 bit integers.

Comment: The XOR operation would be portable and makes sense, the increment on the other hand will yield different results on different architectures.

Comment: `__uint128_t* A = (__uint128_t*)nonce_counter;` incurs alignment issues.  Consider a `union`.

Comment: @mdatsev sadly my system does not support __uint128_t but thanks for the help nonetheless.